# OpenSceneGraph integration with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, integration, openscenegraph

I download OSG stable 3.0.1 x64-64bit files from [this page.](http://openscenegraph.alphapixel.com/osg/downloads/free-openscenegraph-binary-downloads) There are 3 folder on my pc about OSG. They are `bin, OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1-VS9.0.30729-x64-debug-12741, OpenSceneGraph-3.0.1-VS9.0.30729-x64-release-12741`.

I don't understand how I integrate vs2013. There is a file named `osgPlugins-3.0.1`in bin folder. Can I add OSG as a plugin? I don't change enviroment variables/settings yet.

Answer (score 0):

Those files aren't built for VS2013, they are only build for Visual Studio up to 2010.